# App name shows twice downloading from icloud

Tags: codenameone

Mobile App debug build downloads for 80% and shows the App name twice for Mobile App on Home Screen. Please let me know what would cause this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

See this article for a list of things that can go wrong with an iOS build installation: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/my-ios-build-wont-install.html

Notice that the article is a little old so the second entry should probably say the opposite (to make sure you're sending a 64 bit build):

- Make sure you built the debug version and not the appstore version
- Verify that you are sending a 64 bit build
- Check the the UDID is correct
- Make sure the device isn’t locked for installing 3rd party apps
- Check that you "own" the package name
- Make sure the device has a modern enough version of iOS
- Verify that you are using Safari when installing
- Check that the build hint ios.includePush is set in a way that matches your iOS provisioning