# IOS debug build shows app name twice before downloading and after downloading the App

Tags: codenameone

IOS debug Build shows the name of the app twice before downloading from CN1 cloud website. After installing the App, App downloads and show empty image and show the name of the App twice. Please see the attached screenshots and please advise.

Comment: Isn't this the same? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59341949/app-name-shows-twice-downloading-from-icloud

Comment: Yes Shai. I have verified all the steps and I didn't find any discrepancy. Why would the name display twice on the App. Please advise.

Comment: That's a standard issue that shouldn't impact install. What device/OS version are you installing on? What's in the app?